# Inherit Companion Obejct in Children - Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I've read that static methods cannot overridden in Kotlin, so I'm not sure if this is possible, but not being able to do so would result in a lot of repetitious code. Is there any way to achieve the same behavior while moving the `companion object` into the `Parent`? Here is what I have so far

#### Parent.kt

```
abstract class Parent {
    protected val TAG = this::class.java.simpleName
}
```

#### Brother.kt

```
class Brother: Parent() {
    companion object {
        @Volatile private var instance: Brother? = null
        fun getInstance() = instance ?: synchronized(this) {
            instance ?: Brother().also { instance = it }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Sister.kt

```
class Sister: Parent() {
    companion object {
        @Volatile private var instance: Sister? = null
        fun getInstance() = instance ?: synchronized(this) {
            instance ?: Sister().also { instance = it }
        }
    }
}
```

#### main()

```
fun main() {
    println("Hello, ${Brother.getInstance().TAG}")
    println("Hello, ${Sister.getInstance().TAG}")
}
```

**Console Output**:

> Hello, Brother Hello, Sister

Comment: Just to nitpick on the terminology: Kotlin doesn't _have_ static methods.  (Companion objects achieve most of the same things, though in a more flexible way.)  You may be thinking of Java, which has them — but they can't be overridden in Java.  That's because they're resolved statically (at compile time) from the type of reference.  (Calling a static method on an object is just syntactic sugar for calling it on the reference's class.)

Comment: In this case, you might be able to do what you want in a simpler way with [`by lazy`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegated-properties.html#lazy-properties).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this will work for what you're trying to do.

You can create a superclass for objects that do this pattern:

```
open class SingletonAccessor<T: Any> (private val constructor: () -> T){
    @Volatile private var instance: T? = null
    fun getInstance() = instance ?: synchronized(this) {
        instance ?: constructor().also { instance = it }
    }
}
```

And then inherit it from your implementation class companion objects:

```
class Brother private constructor(): Parent() {
    companion object: SingletonAccessor<Brother>(::Brother)
}

class Sister private constructor(): Parent() {
    companion object: SingletonAccessor<Sister>(::Sister)
}
```

This pattern isn't much different from simply making Brother and Sister `object`s, since they have no constructor parameters, but maybe this is just a simplified example.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Tenfour04's answer, I've come up with an alternate approach, which incorporates the `SingletonAccessor` into the `Parent`

```
abstract class Parent<T>(private val constructor: () -> T) {

    @Volatile private var instance: T? = null
    protected val TAG = this::class.java.simpleName

    fun getInstance() = instance ?: synchronized(this) {
        instance ?: constructor().also { instance = it }
    }
}
```

The implementation in the children is the same as before.

Let me know if this answer can be improved further. In particular, I would like to do in the class declaration `class Parent<T: Parent>`, but that doesn't compile. Is there a way to limit the type parameter to itself and its children?